# How to build an input form with Re-base (Firebase) in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm playing around with Firebase and react native and found that [re-base](https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base) is a useful tool. I'm not so much into Redux but believe that rebase will allow me to make my app work something like this

[image: Redux]

I have some design issues on how to set it up. I'm not gonna drop some code because I'm afraid to do the XY-problem.

Imagine I have the following Firebase database setup

```
{"DRAFT 1": {
  "Information A": {
    "Value 1": foo,
    "Value 2": bar,
    "Value 3": baz
  },
  "Information B": {
    "Value 1": '',
    "Value 2": '',
    "Value 3": 'hello world'
  } },
 "DRAFT 2: {
  "Information A": {
    "Value 1": '',
    "Value 2": '',
    "Value 3": ''
  },
  "Information B": {
    "Value 1": '',
    "Value 2": '',
    "Value 3": ''
  } }
}
```

(I don't need to have spaces in the key names but would be nice..)

The screen should show the drafts but also allow me to create a new draft (colored borders indicate components).

[image]

If I press one of the blue button the Firebase ref is stored in the state of the outer blue component (and passed down as prop to the next yellow component).

If I press the green button it will push a new key to Firebase and store it in the state (of the blue component)

Once the picked draft ID is stored in the state (blue component) a new (yellow) component shows and the old one hides (orange). The ID is passed down as prop

[image]

The InputComponents each a JavaScript Objects in their state that can be synced with the Firebase node (got the ref from the props).

if the object doesn't exist in Firebase the component will push/post the object to Firebase and then sync it.

The button in the top right corner is looking at the Firebase node (ref is stored in the state) and some logic checks if if all fields are filled out, then it would be clickable...

Is this a good design or is there a smarter way (no redux thx)?